# Discord.js , Late action on banning the (bot) on my anti channels nuke system

Tags: javascript, security, discord, discord.js

I made a test work for Discord bot to Protect from nuke attemps (in that case its for channels) , which ban or kick (depend member) the member after passing the ratelimit , here , i set if the bot delete 2 channels in raw of 3 secs , he get banned . **But ** , its delaying the action for more seconds , which cause the target to delete most of channels , then the my Bot take the ban action , which is a trouble of late action , thats why i need help :

```
// Anti Channels Nuke !

client.on('channelDelete', async (channel) => {
  try {
    const guild = channel.guild;
    var invitex = null;
    var userId = channel.guild.me.id; // Replace with the actual bot's user ID
    var botUser = channel.guild.members.cache.get(userId);
    var time = 5000;
    var channels = 3;

    var auditLogs = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 'CHANNEL_DELETE', limit: 1 });
    var deletionLog = auditLogs.entries.first();
    var actionUserx = deletionLog.executor;
    var actionMember = guild.members.cache.get(actionUserx.id);

    if (!actionUserx) {return;}
    if (!actionMember){return;}
    let ownerId = guild.ownerId

    if (actionUserx.id == ownerId) { return; }
    if (actionUserx.id == '01231232423423423') { return; }
    if (actionUserx.bot) {
      try {
        if (actionUserx.flags.has('VERIFIED_BOT')) {
          console.log('mass chan del safe with verified bot !'); return;
        } else {
          console.log(`Sus Activity by bot : ${actionUserx.tag} ! delete channels ?`);
          time = 3000;
          channels = 2;
        }
      } catch (error) { console.log('mass chan del safe with verified bot !'); return; }
    } else {
      console.log(`Sus Activity by user : ${actionUserx.username} ! delete channels ?`);
      time = 4000;
      channels = 3;
    }

    var currentTime = Date.now();

    // Check if the user has any previous deletion actions
    if (channelDeletions.has(actionUserx.id)) {
      const deletionData = channelDeletions.get(actionUserx.id);

      // Check if the previous deletion actions were within the specified time frame (3 seconds)
      if (currentTime - deletionData.timestamp <= time) {
        deletionData.count += 1;
        currentTime = Date.now();
        deletionData.timestamp = currentTime;
        // Check if the user has reached the threshold of three consecutive deletions
        if (deletionData.count >= channels) {
          console.log(`${actionUserx.tag} has deleted ${channels} channels in a row. Detected as Nuke ! Taking Action...`);
          
          if (actionUserx.bot) {
            try{
            actionMember.ban({ reason: 'Security Disabled his Nuke Attempt !' })}catch{
              try{
 actionMember.kick({ reason: 'Security Disabled his Nuke Attempt ! , But Couldnt Ban Him !' })
              }catch{console.log('cant do smth about nuker :',actionUserx.id)}
            };
            modlog(guild, 'Nuke Attempt : CHD', `\`#${channel.name}\``, `<@${actionUserx.id}>`, 'Smart Security', 'Permanent Ban', true);
            return;
//modlog(guild,Action,Channel,WhoDid,Admin,TakeAction,Dangerous)
          } else {
    /// Invite Sys
  guild.invites.fetch()
      .then(invites => {
        if (invites.size > 0) {
          const firstInvite = invites.first();
          if (firstInvite) { invitex = firstInvite; }
        } else {
          if (invitex == null) { invitex = invites.first || `null`; }
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error retrieving invites:', error.message);
      });
            
            modlog(guild, 'Possible Nuke Attempt : UCHD', `\`#${channel.name}\``, `<@${actionUserx.id}>`, 'Smart Security', 'Kick with ReInvite', true)

            actionUserx.send({
              content: `${actionUserx}`,
              embeds: [
                {
                  title: 'Smart Security Kicked you!',
                  description: `**You have been Kicked from \`${guild.name}\` for channel Mass Delete (Detected as Nuke!).**\nIf you feel this is a mistake, try deleting channels slowly (2 channels per 3 seconds).\n\nDon't worry, here is a server invite to get back: **discord.gg/${invitex}**\n\n(If there is no invite here, ask the owners to invite you!)`,
                  color: 0xff0000, // Red color
                },
              ],
            })
              .then(() => {
                // Kick the actionUser from the server
                try {
                  deletionData.count = 1;
                  deletionData.timestamp = currentTime;
                  actionUserx.kick('Channel deletion violation')
                } catch { console.log(`cant kick ${actionUserx.tag} error : ${error.message} !`); return; }
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(`Failed to send DM or kick to the actionUser: ${actionUserx.tag} error : ${error.message} !`);
              });
          }
        return;}
      } else {
        // Reset the deletion count and timestamp since the time frame has expired
        deletionData.count = 1;
        deletionData.timestamp = currentTime;
        return;
      }
      return;} else {
      // Add the user to the deletion map with initial count and timestamp
      channelDeletions.set(actionUserx.id, { count: 1, timestamp: currentTime });
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) { console.log('error on total anti nuke chan : ', error) }
});
```

Hope for soon answers ! (also apologizes for my pro english ).

**Tryed :** Nuke protection Bans the bot when passed limit

**Problem :** Late action !